# how to open one item from UIActivityViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have one PDF File I want to open Automatically in UIActivityType.markupAsPDF
that's mean user don't search for markup just go in Markup Button

here is my code :

```
if let pdfUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyPDF", withExtension: "pdf") {
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfUrl], applicationActivities:nil)
    
    
        activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityType.postToFacebook,
            UIActivityType.postToTwitter,
            UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
            UIActivityType.message,
            UIActivityType.mail,
            UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,
            UIActivityType.assignToContact,
            UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
            UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
            UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
            UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
            UIActivityType.airDrop,
            UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
            //UIActivityType.print,
            
            
    ]
    // These activity types shouldn't be excluded
    // UIActivityType.print,
    // UIActivityType.markupAsPDF

    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

in this code user see Menu again but with little choice I want user go exactly in markupAsPDF (Markup) = Pencilkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the markup feature, You have to use `QLPreviewController`.

Here is the wrapped  `QLPreviewController` class.

```
import QuickLook
import PDFKit

class PDFMarkup: QLPreviewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
    
    private var fileURL: URL?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationItem.title = ""
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = nil
    }
    
    deinit {
        debugPrint("‼️‼️‼️ deinit : \(self) ‼️‼️‼️")
    }
    
    
    func openPDFDocument(with vc: UIViewController, documentURL: URL?) {
        
        guard let documentURL = documentURL else {
            print("Cannot open document because it's nil")
            return
        }
        
        if let navController = vc.navigationController {
            navController.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
//            navController.pushViewController(self, animated: true)
        } else {
            vc.show(self, sender: nil)
        }
        
        if QLPreviewController.canPreview(documentURL as QLPreviewItem) {
            self.fileURL = documentURL
            self.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0
            self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self
            self.setEditing(true, animated: true)
            self.reloadData()
            
        } else {
            print("Item not supported by QLPreviewController")
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        self.navigationItem.title = ""
        self.title = ""
        return fileURL! as QLPreviewItem
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        return .updateContents
    }
    
    func previewControllerDidDismiss(_ controller: QLPreviewController) {
        
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didUpdateContentsOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem) {
        
    }
}
```

Usage

```
private let docPreviewer = PDFMarkup()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.docPreviewer.openPDFDocument(with: self, documentURL: /*your document url*/)
}
```

Comment: I really need your help. Could I ask you to open a chatroom to ask some questions?  I really really appreciate your time . I promise you to appreciate it to the highest level

Comment: Where did you stick?

Comment: I think I can not overcome that. I need your help. Are you a member in any other platform like upwork? Or a direct way to communicate

Comment: You can be asked here with your problem and make it a separate question. and attach the git link if you can.